# Lazarus UnicodeToCP857 conversion

Tags: lazarus

i'm developing wince application with Lazarus.
How can i convert string UnicodeToCP857 (MS-DOS Turkish)?
Lazarus dosn't provide for me. How do i convert it?

Comment: You can try [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)

Comment: Use the function posted in the Lazarus forum http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=29999.0, reply #2.